# Flask API using custom Resource subclass methods

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I've been using the following approach to build Flask rest API (this is just a brief example to help you understand my question):

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from models.user import User, UserSchema
from flask import Blueprint, request, make_response

user_service_blueprint = Blueprint('user_service', __name__)
user_schema = UserSchema()
service = Api(user_service_blueprint)

class UserResource(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        # do some work here
        ...

    def patch(self, id):
        # do some work here
        ...

    def delete(self, id):
        ...

service.add_resource(UserResource, '/users/<int:id>')
```

I want to add a new `UserResource` GET method called `get_only_registered_users(self, id: int)` (doesn't matter) and add this to the service with another endpoint, namely `/registered_user/<int: id>`.

I can reach my goal by creating a separate `Resource` subclass, but I am wondering if it can be done by just adding a new method to the `UserResource` class and adding it to the service without creating a separate `Resource` subclass for just one method. Maybe I can use something like `service.add(UserResource.custom_method, '/custom_endpoint/<int:user_id')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to specific the endpoint like:

```
def get(cls, user_id):
    if request.endpoint == 'registered_users':
        // Your logic
    else:
        // Your logic
.....
service.add_resource(UserResource, '/users/<int:id>', endpoint='users')
service.add_resource(UserResource, '/registered_users/<int:id>', endpoint='registered_users')
```